# Is it possible to inject ng-click to an ng-binded html div in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm sending html back from my controller with this function :

```
$scope.filterLocation=function(obj){
 var loc = $filter('filter')( $scope.locationss, {'product_code':obj});
 var htmlstring = "";
 angular.forEach(loc, function(value, key) {
    htmlstring = '<div ng-click="locationModal()">' + htmlstring + value.location_description + '</div>';
 })

 return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlstring);

}
```

I then have this html to show the list of locations :

```
<td><span ng-bind-html="filterLocation(l.productcode)" style="cursor: pointer;"></span></td>
```

The issue is, as you can see in the controller im sort of injecting `'<div ng-click="locationModal()">'` and when i view the inspector the function is there correctly :

```
<span ng-bind-html="filterLocation(l.productcode)" style="cursor: pointer;" class="ng-binding"><div ng-click="locationModal()">A5AL</div></span>
```

But when i try to click it i get no results, is it because it is inside the ng-bind-html? it was a div but i changed it to a span to see if that changed anything.

Comment: [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) would convert string into DOM with `scope` (and therefore a working `ng-click`)

Comment: Using this just returns the functions though i did try to use $compile, cant get it to work

Comment: You should write a directive with `$compile` that you then place on your `<span>` with some use of `$sce.trustAsHtml`. Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3CewDscih8diAo4mMSwJ?p=preview) as an example (or this [neat version with filters too](https://gist.github.com/MeTe-30/ba28805b0805368bd42a9c7e24b54f79))

Comment: I cant do it like that because it is in an ng-repeat, setting a $scope.html cant be an option for this... it needs to be in a function that returns

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this fast for the moment, but hopefully you'll have the begin of an answer.

You could do some workaround like this :

```
$scope.htmlstrings = [];
var string = {
    htmlLoc: ''
};

angular.forEach(loc, function(value, key) {
    string.htmlLoc= string.htmlLoc+ value.location_description;
    $scope.htmlstrings.push(string);
})
```

I don't understand why you do `htmlstring = htmlstring + value.location_description;` tho.

Then :

```
<span ng-init="filterLocation(l.productcode);" ng-repeat="htmlstring in htmlstrings">
    <div ng-click="locationModal();" ng-bind="htmlstring.htmlLoc"></div>
</span>
```

You can change this to a return way with : `<span ng-init="htmlstrings = filterLocation(l.productcode);" ng-repeat="htmlstring in htmlstrings">`

And without using `var string = {}` but `var string = ''` html looks like that:

```
<span ng-init="htmlstrings = filterLocation(l.productcode);" ng-repeat="htmlstring in htmlstrings">
    <div ng-click="locationModal();" ng-bind="htmlstring"></div>
</span>
```

I'll develop this later. Hope it works in your case.